# How to get a compact javascript number via JSON_VALUE

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

With the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
CAST(JSON_VALUE(d.Data,'lax $.realSKosten') AS DECIMAL(18,5)) as ks, 
CONVERT(float ,JSON_VALUE(d.Data,'lax $.realAKosten')) as ka  
FROM UserEntityData as d
```

I get this result:

```
[{"ks":1.23000,"ka":1.230000000000000e+000},
 {"ks":2.34500,"ka":2.345000000000000e+000}]
```

With huge resultsets, a big part of the result consists of zeros. Therefore it would be much better, if the resultset would look like this:

```
[{"ks":1.23,"ka":1.23},
 {"ks":2.345,"ka":2.345}]
```

As shown, with "AS DECIMAL(18,5)" I can shorten it. But the number of decimals is fixed.

Is there a performant way to tell the SQL-Server to remove all zeros at the end, if there are any? Of course without converting it to varchar and doing any text-manipulation.

Comment: That SQL won't return that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not if you want the value to be treated as a numerical value, no. If you're happy with the values being quoted, however, you could use `TRIM`.

```sql
SELECT TRIM('0' FROM CONVERT(varchar(20),ks)) AS ks,
       TRIM('0' FROM CONVERT(varchar(20),ka)) AS ka
FROM (VALUES(1.23000,1.23000), 
            (2.34500,2.34500))V(ks,ka)
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Which results in:

```json
[
    {
        "ks": "1.23",
        "ka": "1.23"
    },
    {
        "ks": "2.345",
        "ka": "2.345"
    }
]
```

Comment: This workaround would reduce the amount of data except for the quotes. But a browser session receiving this data has to convert all the values from text to number. I'm still curious if there is a way to let sql-server doing the type-conversion without the unnecessary zeros at the end.

Comment: From my answer, @SunnySatellite *"Not if you want the value to be treated as a numerical value, no. "* SQL Server uses strongly typed values; it doesn't permit a column to have a variable scale.

Comment: Ok, I think that answers the question. Thanx a lot.